# Pause and start JS countdown timer

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to develop a centurion countdown timer for my website. It is a drinking game.

The way the timer works is: It is a 60 second countdown timer. Everytime the timer hits 0 it will +1 a shot counter and restart. It will do this 100 times.

The game is you must do 1 shot, every minute for 100 minutes. I am a beginner at JS and I am learning a lot, but I am seriously struggling to get this to work the way I want it to.

All I need is a "Start" Button, a "Pause" button and a "Reset" button but I can't seem to find a way to make these buttons work without messing the timer up.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div class="inner">
  <h1 class="heading alt">Centurions Timer</h1>
  <p>1 Shot. Every Minute. 100 Minutes.</p>
  <p>___________________________________</p>
  <div id="timer">
    <p id="seconds">60</p>
    <p id="shots">0</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="timer()">
  <input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="clearInterval(myTimer)">
</div>
```

and here is the JS code:

```
var seconds = 60;
var shots = 0;
var timer;
var c = 60;

function timer() {
    timer = setInterval(myTimer, 1000)
}

function myTimer() {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = --c;
    if (c == 0) {
        shots = shots + 1;
        c = 60;
    }
    document.getElementById("shots").innerHTML = shots;
}
```

If anyone could help me and show me what I am doing wrong and how I can make the code better, please do!

Comment: instead of a timer you may want to consider using requestAnimationFrame - either way a promise that tests whether or not a cached time is met/exceeded is likely a good route. This is because timers are not priority in the Browser Queue.

Answer (score 0):

First, consider renaming either your method `timer()` or variable `timer` to disambiguate between the two.

Next, `setInterval()` returns an interval ID, which you store in `timer`.

`clearInterval()` takes the interval ID as the parameter, so try passing it the `timer` variable instead of `myTimer` (a function)

Answer (score 0):

Little bit clean up needed. For clearInterval, u have to id of timer to clear

```js
var seconds = 60;
var shots = 0;
var timer;
var c = 60;

function start() {
  clearInterval(timer)
  timer = setInterval(( ) =>{
    updateUi()
  }, 1000);
}
function pause() {
  clearInterval(timer)
}
function updateUi() {
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = --c;
  if (c == 0) {
    shots = shots + 1;
    c = 60;
  }
  document.getElementById("shots").innerHTML = shots;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
        <h1 class="heading alt">Centurions Timer</h1>
        <p>1 Shot. Every Minute. 100 Minutes.</p>
        <p>___________________________________</p>
        <div id="timer">
            <p id="seconds">60</p>
            <p id="shots">0</p>
        </div>
        <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
        <input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="pause()">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Pub Sub model, to make code looks clean.

```js
var seconds = 60;
var shots = 0;
var c = 60;
function Emitter() {
  this.cb;
  this.on = cb => {
    this.cb = cb;
  };
  this.emit = () => {
    this.cb && this.cb();
  };
  this.cancel = () => {
    this.cb = null;
  };
}
const emitter = new Emitter();
const tick = () => {
  setInterval(() => {
    emitter.emit();
  }, 1000);
};
tick()
function start() {
  emitter.on(updateUi);
}
function pause() {
  emitter.cancel();
}
function updateUi() {
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = --c;
  if (c == 0) {
    shots = shots + 1;
    c = 60;
  }
  document.getElementById("shots").innerHTML = shots;
}
```

```html
<div class="inner">
    <h1 class="heading alt">Centurions Timer</h1>
    <p>1 Shot. Every Minute. 100 Minutes.</p>
    <p>___________________________________</p>
    <div id="timer">
        <p id="seconds">60</p>
        <p id="shots">0</p>
    </div>
    <input type="button" value="Start" onclick="start()">
    <input type="button" value="Pause" onclick="pause()">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="inner">
  <h1 class="heading alt">Centurions Timer</h1>
  <p>1 Shot. Every Minute. 100 Minutes.</p>
  <p>___________________________________</p>
  <div id="timer">
    <p id="minutes">100</p>
    <p id="seconds">60</p>
    <p id="shots">0</p>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="START" onclick="start()">
  <input type="button" value="PAUSE" onclick="pause()">
  <input type="button" value="RESET" onclick="reset()">
</div>
```

Changed the onclick functions to something more meaningful. Added an extra button and some more logic to auto-stop when hitting the 100 minutes.

```
var seconds = 60,
    minutes = 100,
    shots   = 0;
    timer   = "";

// this will just stop the timer, if you click start it will resume from where it left off
function pause() {
  clearInterval(timer);
}

// resets seconds/minutes/shots, stops game
function reset() {
  clearInterval(timer);
  seconds = 60;
  minutes = 100;
  shots   = 0;
  timer   = "";
  document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = minutes;
  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = c;
  document.getElementById("shots").innerHTML   = shots;
}

// starts game from wherever it was left
function start() {
  timer = setInterval(function() {
    document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = c--;

    if (c === 0) {
      document.getElementById("minutes").innerHTML = --minutes;
      // when 100 minutes are up, game will stop and reset
      if (minutes === 0) {
        reset();
      }

      shots++;
      c = 60;
    }

    document.getElementById("shots").innerHTML = shots;
  }, 1000)
}
```